# Create Composite Key and Unique - Security Multi tenant

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In multi tenant application, we can force the ID that is in another tenant in input

In SQL Server I resolve as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tenant (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
    id INT  NOT NULL,
    id_tenant INT  NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_tenant) REFERENCES tenant(id),

    -- pra ter a FK composta, tem que ter chave composta na tabela de origem
    UNIQUE (Id,id_tenant)
);

CREATE TABLE [order]  (
    id INT  NOT NULL,
    id_customer INT  NOT NULL,
    id_tenant INT  NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_customer, id_tenant) REFERENCES customer (id, id_tenant),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_tenant) REFERENCES tenant(id)
);
```

How would I do the mapping with my models?
How to generate my models with SQL above? With Code First?

```
public class Tenant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you looking for is a model like this:

```
public class Tenant
{
    [Key]   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key,ForeignKey("Tenant"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to learn about the annotations I used in this model, you can check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx)

### Update

Yes, you can have multiples FK properties in an entity as part of the configuration of other relationships, for example, suppose you want to relate the customers with a Group:

```
 public class Group
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers {get ; set;}
 }
```

Then, in your `Customer` class you can have a FK property to the Group Table. Add this:

```
  public class Customer
  {
     //...
     [ForeignKey("Group")
     public int GroupId { get; set; }

     public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, the idea is not to allow add customer if it does not have the same tenant, and if I have other properties in addition the customerId?

Comment: that's right, having a composite PKs ensures that you are not going to have customers with the same 'TenantId'. What you mean with "having another properties"?

Comment: in example, I have CustomerId, and in property TenantId use ForeignKey(Customer), and if other property? groupId, otherId

Comment: In int TenantId I can have multiple foreingkey ? sorry my english

Comment: Hello@Rod, check the update, I hope that is what you asking for